# How can I change the order of method delegation in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming

My goal is to change the order of method delegation in Groovy so that I can dynamically override methods in a Groovy object.

I have a class called `Weapon` defined below:

```
class Weapon {
    Prefix prefix

    String method() {
        'Called from Weapon'
    }
}
```

where `prefix` is an instance of this class:

```
class Prefix {
    final Map<String, Closure> methods = [:]

    void propertyMissing(String name, Closure value) {
        if (value != null) {
            methods[name] = value
        }
        else {
            methods.remove(name)
        }
    }

    def methodMissing(String name, args) {
        if (!methods.containsKey(name)) {
            throw new MissingMethodException(name, Prefix, args)
        }
        methods.(name)(args)
    }
}
```

This design allows for a `Prefix` to dynamically add methods at runtime.

The *specific* desired behavior is that any method called by a `Weapon` will first search for it in `prefix` (if it is not null). If it isn't there, then the `Weapon` will search for the method using its normal behavior (as seen here: https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/core-metaprogramming.html#_runtime_metaprogramming).

Here is a simple example of the desired behavior:

```
Weapon w = new Weapon()
Prefix p = new Prefix()

p.method = { 'Called from Prefix' }
w.prefix = p

assert w.method() == 'Called from Prefix'

w.prefix = null

assert w.method() == 'Called from Weapon'
```

I am fairly new to Groovy's metaprogramming, so I am not aware of all of its capabilities by any stretch. At first, I thought I could do this by simply overriding the `invokeMethod` method in Weapon, but Groovy ended up finding the method before `invokeMethod` was ever called (I assume it was found in the metaclass or class).

The only solution I can think of is to create a custom MetaClass for `Weapon` which would first check the `Weapon`'s prefix. My implementation for that is below:

```
class WeaponMetaClass {
    WeaponMetaClass(MetaClass metaClass) {
        super(metaClass)
    }
    Object invokeMethod(Object object, String methodName, Object[] args) {
        if (object instanceof Weapon && object.prefix != null) {
            try {
                return object.prefix.(methodName)(args)
            }
            catch (MissingMethodException ignored) {
            }
        }
        return super.invokeMethod(object, methodName, args)
    }
}
```

However, this did not work, and every method call from a `Weapon` (with or without `prefix`) returned null instead. Have I made a mistake in my implementation, is there a better way of doing this, or is this not even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use default metaClass to achieve the required behavior

```
class Weapon {
    void setPrefix(Map m){
        this.metaClass=null                     //reset to default class behavior
        if(m)m.each{k,v-> this.metaClass[k]=v}  //redefine methods/properties from map
    }

    String method() {
        'Called from Weapon'
    }
}

def w = new Weapon()
//you could wrap prefix with custom class - however it's just a map container
def prefix=[
    method: {'Called from Prefix'}
]


assert w.method()=='Called from Weapon'

w.prefix = prefix
assert w.method()=='Called from Prefix'

w.prefix = null
assert w.method()=='Called from Weapon'
```